# The only point of $\operatorname{Spec} (k[x,y] /(y^2,xy))$ with nonreduced stalk is the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, localization, affine-schemes

This is exercise 5.2.C in Vakil's lecture notes. I was able to show that $(k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_x \simeq k[x]_x \simeq k(x)$ is reduced.

Now how does it follow that the only point with nonreduced stalk is the origin ?
If I localize at the origin, I get $(k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x,y)}$. But I don't see why this is nonreduced.

Progress:
I am still stuck with this exercise.
I cannot take $y \in (k[x,y]/(y^2,xy))_{(x,y)}$, as then $y = 0$ since $xy = 0$. (in the localization). I get the same problem for $x$. There seem to be only constants left ?

Comment: You've made a mistake in part 1: $k[x]_x\not\cong k(x)$, but it is isomorphic to a different reduced ring. In part 2, do you know what being non-reduced means? It means that there's an element with a particular property. Do you see any guesses for that element, say already written down in your post somewhere?

Comment: I don't see what other ring $k[x]_x$ is isomorphic to. I fear I might be misunderstanding something there. Clearly, $y$ is an unreduced element in the initial ring $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$. Intuitively, it should then also be unreduced in the localization at $(x,y)$.

Comment: The point is that $k[x]_x$ is not a field and therefore cannot be $k(x)$: the element $x-1$ is not invertible, for instance. $k[x]_x\cong k[x,x^{-1}]$ which is still an integral domain. You're on the right track with the guess - what happens if you try to prove this? If you get stuck, please [edit] your progress in to your question.

Comment: Why do you think $y=0$ in the localization $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y^2,xy)$? That's not true! It seems you're dealing with some misconceptions here - in order to get help with those issues, it might help you to explain your thought process a little more in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previously noted in the comments, $(k[x,y]/(xy,y^2))_x\cong k[x]_x$ is reduced.

On the other hand, $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy,y^2)$ is not reduced - $y$ is a nonzero element that squares to zero.

To show that $y\neq 0$ in $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy,y^2)$, we use the definition of localization: in a ring $R$ with multiplicatively closed subset $S$, the equality $\frac{r}{s}=\frac{r'}{s'}$ holds in $S^{-1}R$ iff there exists a $u\in S$ so that $u(rs'-r's)=0$ in $R$. In our case, we're looking to show that $\frac{y}{1}\neq \frac{0}{1}$.

To make the calculation slightly more understandable, we'll lift to $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ - this means we're now on the hook for showing that there's no $u\in k[x,y]\setminus (x,y)$ such that $uy\in (xy,y^2)$. But this is straightforward: an element $u\in k[x,y]$ is not in $(x,y)$ iff it has a nonzero constant term, so we can write $u=c+p$ for $p\in(x,y)$ and $c\in k\setminus 0$. So $uy=cy+yp$ is not in $(xy,y^2)$ because $cy$ is not in $(xy,y^2)$, and so $y\neq 0$ in $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy,y^2)$.